# An awkwardly repeated sentence needs some polish

Tags: prepositions, repetition

What would be a better expression for the following?

> Kudos to Peter FOR his volunteering FOR Sunday school FOR both Jan and Feb.

There certainly are many OTHER ways to express my gratitude to Peter's help. But I feel a "lengthy" expression can easily diminish the "sense of gratitude" I wish to convey so I am hoping for a concise expression that gets right to the point but won't be hampered by the repetition of 3 'for' in a row.

Details: I was suggested to add more details so that people can provide on-point corrections: Peter, when approached, chose to help out church's Sunday school (but not the outreach programs due to scheduling conflicts) and volunteered for two months' time instead of the regular one month. His spirit exemplified an exceptional role model at church and I would like to encourage others to emulate Peter by expressing my gratitude to his altruism.

Comment: Well, you can get rid of the middle "for" by replacing "for" with "to teach" or whatever term fits what the "for" is replacing. Similarly, you can get rid of the first one by changing it to "who has volunteered". This is negligibly longer.

Answer (score 2):

*for* is not the best preposition to use in every phrase here. I would write:

> Kudos to Peter **for** his volunteering **at** Sunday school, **during** both Jan and Feb.

Comment: The logic for the second and third choice of for is as follows: there are many other opportunities to volunteer at the same time (12-1pm) but Peter chose to volunteer "for" Sunday school; as to Jan and Feb, most people opt for only one month of volunteering but he chose to do it "for" two months. Would you still replace the second "for" with "at" and the third with "during"?

Comment: Of course context might change what you write. If you want to know for your situation, pls edit your question.